# for loop multiple variables

Tags: linux, bash, scripting

I've two text files and I want to put each line from both files as output i.e.

```
#!/bin/bash
u=`cat newlist`
for i in $u 
do
echo ""
echo ",'$i'"

for b in $( cat password )
do
echo ",'$b'"
done
done
```

Output should be

```
abc - from Users file 'line # 1'
123 - from password file 'line # 1'
```

Any help please

Comment: Do you want to print the 1st line from each file followed by the 2nd line from each and so on ?

Comment: Yes exactly. you got my point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash
exec 8<passwordfile
while read user
do
    read password <&8
    echo $user
    echo $password
done <usersfile
```

Comment: That's quite elegant.

Answer (score 1):

[`paste`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/paste)

Also, [BASH FAQ entry #1](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001).

Comment: Also, that code snippet makes me want to gouge out my eyes.